# Counting Line Tiles in Video to Pass The Line in video

Tags: python, opencv

I have small project to count how many horizontal lines in floor tiles that pass the line that i create in video. But i dont know how to make the program to count the line that i already detect that pass the line that i created.
The code so far is:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2


def get_gauss_kernel(size, sigma, teta, gamma, lmbda):
    center = (int)(size/2)
    kernel = np.zeros((size, size))
    for i in range(-center, center + 1, 1):
        for j in range(-center, center + 1, 1):
            x1 = i * math.cos(teta) + j * math.sin(teta)
            y1 = -1 * i * math.sin(teta) + j * math.cos(teta)
            kernel[i+2,j+2] = np.exp(-(x1**2 + gamma**2 * y1**2) / (2 * sigma ** 2)) * math.cos(2 * math.pi * x1 / lmbda)
    return kernel

video = cv2.VideoCapture("jalantes.mp4")
kernel2 = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
kernel3 = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
#akses video
while(True):
    #detecting horizontal line
    ret, orig_frame = video.read()   
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(orig_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
    canny1 = cv2.Canny(blur, threshold1=75, threshold2=100)
    sobely = cv2.Sobel(blur, ddepth=-1, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=1)
    
    kernelku = get_gauss_kernel(25, 5, 0, 1, 15)

    hasil = cv2.filter2D(sobely, ddepth=-1, kernel=kernelku)
    ret,thresh1=cv2.threshold(hasil, 220, 255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
    erosion = cv2.erode(thresh1, kernel2, iterations=1)
    dilate = cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel3, iterations=1)
    ret,thresh2=cv2.threshold(dilate, 220, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)


    #creating line
    cv2.line(orig_frame, (0,512), (2400,512), (0,255,0), 3)

    
    cv2.imshow('Original', orig_frame)
    cv2.imshow('Hasil', thresh2)

    if cv2.waitKey(1)>0:
        break
    
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How to make a program to count how many horizontal line in the floor detected that pass the line i create using cv2.line?

Comment: We can't run your program because you did not provide your resource (the video). Without your complete input it is very hard to help you.

Comment: not even a video is needed, just a picture. -- and may I recommend moving the calculation of constants out of the loop, such as `kernelku` -- and **that** `center = (int)(size/2)` is **silly** python. write `int(size/2)`. we aren't doing C casts here. the parens around `int` have no special meaning in python.

Comment: https://youtu.be/gmT7caz6g3Q this is the video that i used for this program. I want to count how many steps of floor tiles (vertically) in the video.

Comment: Please elaborate on the *"But i dont know how to make the program to count the line that i already detect that pass the line that i created."* as I do not quite understand. Thanks!

Comment: @artpdb The youtube video you posted are the wrong dimensions compared to your cade. Can you edit your code to correspond to the video that you can share?